# Graph engine for retrive movie relations

Tags: mysql, graph, neo4j, orientdb, arangodb

I have many small graphs (title relations: prequel, sequel, adaptation, ...)
and I want to retrieve all graphs that contain the title from the given collection. For query: `Harry Potter 2`, `Star Wars 3`, `Harry Potter 1` I want to get 2 vertex-edge collections.

I was checking Neo4j, GUN, OrientDB, Arango, but I don't find this.

Can you recommend a solution based on a free/FOSS graph db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OrientDB is free open source software, you can download it here http://orientdb.com/download/

Suppose you have a class called `Movie` with an attribute called `title`, you can write a query as follows:

```
TRAVERSE bothE(), bothV() FROM (
   SELECT FROM Movie WHERE title IN ["Harry Potter 2", "Star Wars 3"]
)
```

You can also specify one or more edge classes if you want to limit the traversal:

```
TRAVERSE bothE("prequel", "sequel"), bothV() FROM (
   SELECT FROM Movie WHERE title IN ["Harry Potter 2", "Star Wars 3"]
)
```

This will return all the vertices and edges connected to movies with those titles.

You can also add a Lucene index to the `title` property and perform full text queries with stemming and all the rest

I hope it helps

Comment: This is not exactly what I needed (one list) but sufficient for my needs.
In addition, you can build a recommendation system on the OrientDB. It looks promising.